# vim: how can you get netrw to open https links?

Tags: vim

In Vim I can open `http:` links with `gf`. But `gf` on `https:` links don't seem to work. (Vim just creates a new buffer linked to a long filename.) Is there some configuration settting I can tweak to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but feel free to be the one to fix netrw to make it possible! It's probably not all *that* hard -- on a quick inspection, you would need to modify the `autocmd` patterns in `plugin/netrwPlugin.vim` to match `https://*`, and then either:

#### Option A

1. In `autoload/netrw.vim`, add a new `netrw_method` number for https, a new pattern in `NetRwMethod` to match https urls, and a few lines of code just like the http one to set the method and other vars correctly.
2. Add code in `NetRead` to deal with the new method number -- possibly by creating a new local variable for the scheme, setting that, and then falling into a common codepath for either http or https.

#### Option B

1. In `autoload/netrw.vim`, modify the `httpurm` pattern so that it will match either http or https URLs, and captures the scheme (or at least the "s") so you can tell which is which.
2. Hijack the `b:netrw_option` variable to signal whether http or https is wanted (the `fetch` method already does something similar).
3. Make the `NetRead` http codepath aware of this fact, so that it puts "http" or "https" into the commandline as appropriate instead of being full of hardcoded "http".